# Split a column in a dataframe after every four values set into 4 columns in new dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with 1 column and 162424 rows.

I want to create a new df from this;

First three values in original dataframe should be divided into four new columns in first row in new df.

Next three values in original dataframe should be divided into four columns in second row in new df.

And so on.

Original df size - 1 column, 162424 rows

New df size - 4 columns, 40606 rows

Comment: Please review [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

```
m = data.frame(x = sample(1:12))
as.data.frame(matrix(m$x, ncol = 3, byrow = T))
```